# Python for loop prints every item twice after count reaches 10

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, output

> For some reason, once the loop reaches the 10th item in the to-do list, it starts printing every to-do list item 2x, as in the following example:

```
**Sample output:
1.Walk the dog
2.Make the bed
...
10.Take out the trash
11.Take out the trash
12.Call Sara
13.Call Sara** 

...python
for item in mylist:
    print(item)

name = input("What is your name?")
print(name + "\'s To-Do-List")

mylist = []
count = 1
while True:
    newitem = input("What do you want to add to your to-do-list?")

    if newitem == "nothing" or newitem == "NOTHING" or newitem == "Nothing":
        print("\n")
        print("Your to-do-list is complete!")
        print("You have " + str(count - 1) + " items on your to-do-list: \n")
        for item in mylist:
            print(item)
        break

print(str(count) + ": " + newitem)
    for i in str(count):
        mylist.append(newitem)
    count += 1
```

...

Comment: Probably because you use `for i in str(count)`. 10 has two digits so that is looped  twice.

Comment: Thank you so much!  That helps!  The only problem I have now, would be how to print the entire list as a summary, with the rank/count of each number before each newitem eg given: 1: Wake up.  \n 2:  Make the bed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Rakesh for helping to clean this up but I think it is still not consistent with the observation in the question. The print line just before the for loop is probably indented as well.

I think the line that caused your double-printing is:

```
for i in str(count):
```

You casted your count variable as string and therefore numbers from 10 onwards would iterate twice [1,0], and from 100 onwards, thrice [1,0,0]. Essentially, these are the number of characters in your string.

In any case, it doesn't look to me like you need a for loop here, unless you're trying to do something that I haven't understood. Simply

```
print(str(count) + ": " + newitem)
mylist.append(newitem)
count += 1
```

Comment: I know "for item in enumerate(mylist, start=1): \n \t print(item) would include the number next to the newitem, but I don't like the formatting that results.

Comment: for count,item in enumerate(mylist,start=1) \n \t print("{}: {}".format(count,item))